# Sorting of collection properties

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using WCF Data Services over an ADO.NET Entity Data Model, and I have a 'Customer' object with 'Orders' collection.

I have a SINGLE query which returns the Customer object, with an embedded Orders collection.

How do I specify, through an OData URI (or any mechanism, in fact), that I want the 'Orders' collection to be sorted by a particular property?

My PK for my Order object is a Guid, so if I simply rely on database order, I basically get back a random order on my Orders collection, which is less than ideal...

Note: This must be done with a single query, I dont want to query for the customer, then have to query again for the orders.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OData protocol currently doesn't have a way to do this.
You might try to use service operations to run the query for you, but then it would have to return IQueryable and the client would still need to ask for the $expand (since you can't auto-expand on the server). Not sure if this would work for EF provider, but it might.